# Js closure and the garbage collector

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, closures

> JavaScript is a garbage collected language, meaning that memory is
>   allocated to objects upon their creation and reclaimed by the browser
>   when there are no **more references to them.**

If I understand closures, when I define a closure, there is always a reference to the scope of the outside function, so when are closures fully destroyed?

Comment: Usually it's narrowed down to reachable objects only. So, not the whole scope, but the objects you can address. To be precise the standard does not specify an implementation ought to have a GC. So it's fine if a js implementation does not have one at all.

Comment: When there’s no reference to the closure. Ignore the function aspect and just consider the context part: `var foo = {}; var f = function () { return foo; };` will free `foo` when `f` is no longer referenced in the same way that `var foo = {}; var x = { foo: foo };` would. (This is about *ability*, though; as zerkms said, what actually happens is up to the implementation.)